# Numbering shows on the first page of every chapter and skips any other pages!

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering

I'm using book document class to draft my thesis. But I have difficulty enumerating pages. It shows numbers on the first page of every chapter, and they disappear! Also, I want to counter the Abstract page, but it ignores that too!
I would like to have roman numbers for pages from the beginning to the List of Contents and have arabic numbers afterwards.

This is the piece of code that I'm using. I appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Blah blah blah...
\begin{center}
We hereby approve this thesis for...
\end{center}


ACKNOWLEDGMENTS goes here!

\pagestyle{empty}
\newpage 

Abstract goes here!
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\mainmatter

\input{Chapter1}
\input{Chapter2}
\input{Chapter3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have specified `\pagestyle{empty}` so there are no page numbers, except on chapter openings, where `\chapter` does `\thispagestyle{plain}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did that, but it did not help! Thanks though.

Comment: It is impossible to run your example as you have not provided usable code but the reason you have no page numbers is because you have `\pagestyle{empty}` what did you want that command to do, it has exactly the effect you describe: it removes all the page numbers except on chapter openings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed that command, but still I do not get numbers on any other pages!

Comment: I managed to get what I wanted! I kept \pagestyle{empty} in order to not have any number on the "Acknowledgment" page. However, I put \pagestyle{plain} right before \mainmatter. It works out!

Comment: \pagestyle{empty}  affects the _whole document_ if you just want to affect one page you should use `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: Is the problem resolved by now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reason was a stray `\agestyle{empty}`  in the document.